# In ie11 ajax call -window.location redirect not working, extjs

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, extjs, window.location

I am facing an issue with redirecting to another domain, from ajax call success in ie. It shows issue only in ie, in chrome and firebox it works well. I am using extjs for ajax call and in response i want to redirect to another domain based on the success value.

But if i place an javascript alert in the ajax success it works in ie.

If we place the same redirection code outside success of ajax call it works.

```
           Ext.Ajax.request({
              url: 'API/LogOut.ashx',
              scope: this,

             success: function (response) {
                var result = response.result.data;

                if (result['LogOutUrl'])
                {
                    window.location.assign(result['LogOutUrl']);
```

I even tried to redirect like this window.location.assign('/tax.aspx'). But even this is not working. Anybody has any clue on that.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue for IE browser, in IE due to security it blocks window redirection like window.open().It results in popup blocker.

Try using delayed task or setTimeout() after your ajax response comes.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
          url: 'API/LogOut.ashx',
          scope: this,
         success: function (response) {
            var result = response.result.data;
            if (result['LogOutUrl'])
            {
                setTimeout(function(){
                   window.location.assign(result['LogOutUrl']);
                },1000);
             ...
```

Post your result here.If possible give some fiddle link.

Comment: @NayasSubramanian: can u please create fiddle so that we can get working example and we can fix this over there.